# mongo query seems to be getting slower and slower

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using using spring boot trying to retrieve a set of documents from a mongo db (4.2).  There is about a million documents to retrieve.  I am using Paging and getting 100 documents at a time.

```
findByCreatedDateLessThanAndStatusInAndFlagNot
```

There is an index on CreatedDate, there are 5 possible statuses (I am trying to find 2 of them).  When I find a document I am then using MongoTemplate to then set the flag as true (so it wont come back in the next query).  I am setting the paging so that it only gets page 0(updating the flag, would mean these docs are then not returned in the next call).

The first thousand calls are rapid, about a second, but then it just starts getting slower and slower and some calls were taking 20 minutes to return a result.  Any thoughts or ideas much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to index state and flag, as well?

Comment: I haven’t. I thought as the status would only have 5 possible values and the flag 2 that the index wouldn’t really be that efficient for them. Also doesn’t explain how the first calls were so quick

Answer (score 0):

This query in the later pages will be worse than a collection scan.

From the description, you have documents that contain:

```
{
  CreatedDate: ISODate(),
  Status: "one", // of five
  Seen: false
}
```

There is an index on

```
{ CreatedDate: 1}
```

And you are running a query similar to:

```
Collection.find({
     CreateDate:{$lte:ISODate()}, 
     Status: {$in:["one","two"]},
     Seen: false
}).limit(100)
```

You then retrieve those documents, and send a (hopefully bulk) update to set the `Seen` flag to true for each, and then run the query again to find the second batch.

Assuming even distribution of the status values, looking for 2 out of 5 implies about 40% of the data set, so 1 million documents to return would suggest that there are ~2.25 million documents that match the date.

#### How the query runs

On the first run, the database will begin scanning the index starting with the oldest value, load the document into memory, and examine the `Status` and `Seen` fields.

If the document matches, it is added to the result set, if not it is discarded, and the next one loaded.

When the result set reaches 100 documents, the query executor sends the batch, and terminates the query.

Assuming the statuses are evenly distributed, this will mean 225 documents are examined to return the first 100.

So far so good ... but we're not done:

After the update, when the second batch is requested, the database will begin scanning the index starting with the oldest value, load the document into memory, and examine the `Status` and `Seen` fields.

It won't match, because `Seen` was updated to true after the previous query.  It will re-examine the first 225 documents that match the date, and find nothing to add to the result set.  It will likely have to examine another 225 documents after that to find 100 matches.

As this goes along, the 1000th batch will need to examine the 225,000 documents that had been examined before, and then 225 that hadn't, the 1001st 225,225 + 225, and so on.

To return 1 million document 100 at a time will take 10,000 batches.  The final batch will examine 2,250,000 documents to return 100.

At some point, it is likely that some of the early documents will need to be evicted to make room to examine the later ones.  When that happens, there will be a big jump in how long each batch takes from then on.

Overall this entire operation will have examined the first 225 documents 10,000 times, the second 225 documents 9,999 times, etc.  A grand total of over ***11 billion*** document examinations will have occurred to return those 1 million documents in batches of 100.

If you are using a computer that can load and examine 1,000,000 documents per second, the complete operation will take around 3 hours to identify the million documents to return, not counting network round trips or updates.

#### How to improve this?

Create an index on `{ CreatedDate: 1, Seen: 1 }`

If that index is available, the database will be able to skip the already seen documents during the index scan, so they will not need to be examined.  This would mean that you only need to examine 225 documents for each batch, and the overall operation would return the million documents with only 2,250,000 document examinations, a reduction of ~99.98%.

#### To improve a little bit more:

Create an index on `{ CreatedDate: 1, Status: 1, Seen: 1}`

If that index is available, in the index scan the database can skip over documents that don't have the right status as well.  This will further reduce the document examinations to 1,000,000, i.e. 1:1 with the documents returned.

Comment: Wow thanks for this detailed explanation, will add the index and see how it goes.

Comment: I tried adding that last index. Each query was taking approx 2 minutes. Not sure where to go from here to improve it.

Comment: Check with `explain` to see what it is doing.